# How would you manage a std::vector of structs with std::vectors with large range of sizes in both dimentions?

Tags: c++, stdvector, sparse-matrix

I have a set of structures similar to:

```
typedef struct {
   int a;
   int b;
} ITEM;

typedef struct {
   int orderID;
   std::vector<ITEM> items;
} ORDER;

typedef struct {
   int orderSetID;
   std::vector<ORDER> Orders;
} ORDER_SET;
```

The problem is that the number of orders ranges between 100,000 to 10,000,000 and the number of `ITEMS` in an `ORDER` ranges from 1 to 500.

The issue is, as I build the `ORDER_SET`, I don't know how many ORDERs there will be. I do know when I add an `ORDER` how many ITEMS there will be.
Here are some problems:

1) Ideally once I allocate the memory for all of the ORDERs using Orders.resize(), I'd be able to reuse the memory, but it appears that `Orders.clear()` does delete it all.

2) I start with a somewhat reasonable size for Orders, say `Orders.resize(500,000)`, but the problem is that when I hit large numbers of orders the resize of the Orders vector takes forever because it has to copy all of the `ORDER.item` vectors.

Seems like a similar issue to storing spare matrixes, the issue being that I also don't know how large the structure is going to be before I create it.

Additional information:
1) Using Visual Studio 2008
2) As posted in the comments below I was able to improve the construction of an `ORDER_SET` which contains 10000000 Orders in a reasonable time by replacing `items` with two fields leaving:

```
typedef struct {
    int orderID;
   ITEM singleItem;
   std::vector<ITEM> *pItems;
} ORDER;
```

I put all of the pItems into a separate vector which I use for deleting later.

Now the big issue left is that it appears that calling `ORDER_SET.Orders.clear()` takes quite some time. I'm not sure why though.

Is there a call like clear() which doesn't release the memory, but just sets `end` to `begin`? Once the vector has gotten that large, there really isn't any reason to free the memory, since I might need it again.

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to understand but the whole point of vectors is that they resize themselves, use push_back and all the work should be done for u

Comment: sounds like you need a hybrid structure. Appears to the outside to be a vector, but when you need to resize it, it just allocates a new array that's twice the size of the original and link the new one and the old one together, and so on... This way, you don't suffer the performance loss for copying. But eventually the lookup speed may be affected (however I doubt you'd ever get to THAT BIG). not sure if the STL has such container tho.

Comment: Also what you can do, is to declare Orders as the type `std::vector<ORDER*> Orders` instead, and allocate them on the heap. This way when you copy it over during resize, you only suffer copying over the 100,000 or so pointers. Not the best, but better than what you have now. (But do remember to clean up)

Comment: @BeyondSora Or you could use smart pointers (std::unique_ptr should do the trick) to allocate on the heap and have the smart-ptr clean up for you. But the real thing to do is to implement the move semantics for these classes.

Comment: Also, you should use .reserve rather than .resize, which will allow you to use push_back semantics while limiting the number of resizes.

Comment: I've done a mixture of things which has lead to a speed up of %50.
Most of my Orders only have one Item, so as a bit of a performance hack, I've changed Order to be:  
    typedef struct {
       int orderID;
       ITEM singleItem;
       std::vector<ITEM> *pItems;
    } ORDER;
If the order has more than one item, I create a new std::vector<ITEM> on the heap, and throw the pointer into another vector. When I clean up, I only have to delete all the items in that vector.

The problem I'm seeing now is that when I call ORDER_SET.Orders.clear(), it takes 10 seconds to destroy the 10000000 Orders.

Answer (score 1):

Second issue can be fixed by using C++11 with move semantics of `vector`s, so `ORDER` can be moved, not just deep copied.

`ORDER.Orders.clear()` takes some time because it must call destructors on all elements.

Comment: I just confirmed the default move is not good enough (annoyingly) you'll have to do it yourself. Should be done on both levels (will save you a ton in resizing costs).